# Fill a crack in the granite countertop

Tags: crack, kitchen-counters, granite

I have granite countertops in the kitchen. Recently I noticed there was a very think crack right where 2 slabs join each other. It is about 2 in away from the edge of the slab.

I'm looking for a solution to seal the crack. I have tried Liquid Nails but is is yellow in color and my granite is almost black with copper speckles.

What would be the best DIY way to seal it permanently and make sure it does not widen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical thing to use when joining the two slabs would be epoxy, clear or tinted to match the color of the stone.

It's been a while since I've used it, so I don't know how easy it is to find 'pourable' epoxy that's intended for repairs after installation.  (we used to use it for making composite structures, as you can spread it really thinly).  You'd likely want to find the thinnest (least viscous) formula if it's a very narrow crack.

Comment: the epoxy can be injected into the crack with a small needle, like an oiling needle. Normally, the repair would be polished with a 2 inch high speed buffer with 2600 grit paste 24 hours after the epoxy is applied and fully cured.

Comment: Is it a 2 part epoxy kind? Could you provide a link to Home Depot / Lowes? Thanks a lot!